# ROS2 Humble API documentation

Tags: ros, ros2, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can anyone point me to the ROS2 Humble API documentation?

I found ROS2 API documentation for past distributions at https://docs.ros2.org, e.g.:

https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/
[https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/](https://docs.ros2.org/galactid/api/)

But there's no such link for Humble.

I found that there's also a "latest", but even that one is outdated wrt the doxygen info in the installed .hpp files (installed from Ubuntu packages):

https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/

Thanks, 
Johan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409840/ros2-humble-api-documentation/) by [jrtg](https://answers.ros.org/users/124778/jrtg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2022-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More or less by chance I found the 'Curated List of common ROS2 packages' ([REP 2005](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2005.html)), which contains links per package to the [ROS Index](https://index.ros.org/), and there I found the link to the api documentation.

Turns out that the humble API docs are at http://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/  as opposed to the previous ROS2 distributions at https://docs.ros2.org.

---

Originally posted by [jrtg](https://answers.ros.org/users/124778/jrtg/) with karma: 145 on 2022-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2023-06-02**:
Yes, I had trouble with this in the past. Now, at least, there's a link to the autogenerated API docs on the Humble, Rolling and Iron API Documentation pages (https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/API-Docs.html, for example):

> A raw list of Humble package documentation [may be found here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/) .

It's unfortunate that these still don't really seem to show up in search engine queries for the package and API features in question.

There's some discussion here:

https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1354

and here:

https://discourse.ros.org/t/plans-for-ros-2-documentation-particularly-api-docs/28638/2